# Recursive tuple

Tags: c#, recursion, forward-declaration

I am trying to create a recursive Tuple in C#. One side is a reference a class, and the other side goes into recursion to a likewise datastructure. The right side can be null, and this is when the recursion ends.

At the moment I am using an alias, but this does not seem to work.

```
using Relation = System.Tuple<Node, Relation>;
```

Directly typing this is not possible, as this goes infinite.

```
System.Tuple<Node, System.Tuple<Node, System.Tuple<Node, ...>>>
```

1.
Is this possible in C#?

2.
Can I do this with aliases?

**Extra info**

I am doing this because I need to keep track the parent of each node. A node can have multiple children. I cannot edit the node class.

I only need to go up the hierarchy. i.e. I don't need to know a nodes children. I use this for an algorithm where I calculate alot of nodes, and when I find one, I want to find the path to it from bottom to root.

Comment: An interesting excercise, but in the end this is just a simple list of `Node`s, isn't it? I.e. in an actual scenario you'd just use `List<Node>`?

Comment: I am doing this because I need to keep track the parent of each node. A node can have multiple children. I cannot edit the node class.

Comment: I think `Tuple` is a bad way to go about this. Do something with lists, maybe a class that has `Node Node` and `IList<Node> Children` properties.

Comment: I only need to go up the hierarchy. i.e. I don't need to know a nodes children. I use this for an algorithm where I calculate alot of nodes, and when I find one, I want to find the path to it from bottom to root.

Comment: What you're describing is a manual linked list.  Just use the framework's `LinkedList` type.

Comment: Ha, ofcourse. Why didn't I see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a Class for this.

```
class Relation
{
   Node Node;  // Node is another class
   Tuple<Node, Relation> Relation;
}
```

Comment: This seems inconvenient to me. Isn't there a posibility to go into recursion with generics? If not I might create my own class and use that instead of the tuple indeed.